# HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request when try to save Date to Data Base

Tags: java, hibernate, date, spring-mvc

JSP page:

```
<form:input path="comment"/><br>
<form:input path="date"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Controller:

```
 @PostMapping("/saveVisit")
public String saveVisit(@ModelAttribute Visit visit){
    visitService.addVisit(visit);
    return "redirect:/visit/list";
}
```

And Hibernate Session:

```
 @Override
@Transactional
public void addVisit(Visit visit) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(visit);
}
```

It works when there is no date input, because it can be NULL.

How to preperty input the date and save it in Java Object java.util.date then save it into Data Base?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#format-configuring-formatting-globaldatetimeformat

Comment: @Raspberry  Edited the answer for the new API jdk8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the steps.

1. Create a column of type date

   ```
   @Column(name = "DATEOFBIRTH", nullable = false, length = 32)
   private Date dateOfBirth;
   ```

Using  old API 
2a. Convert the string being received as input to date using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
    public static Date convertStringToDate(String dateInString) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Save the date being returned to the database along with other data

Using New API for only date

```
2b. String str = "01/01/2015";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter)); // not using toString
```

Using New API for date time

```
2c. String str = "01/01/2015 12:32:21";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter)); // not using toString
```

Comment: Isn’t there a way to avoid the outdated classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`? Can `java.time` be used instead?

Comment: I think yes will post an answer once I try it out